# Combining resize+extend with composite in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

Is it possible to combine the following two lines of commands into one?

```bash
# resize the base image to 780x780, and place it at the South of a canvas(1000x1000)
convert base.jpeg \
-resize 780x780^ \
-gravity south \
-extent 1000x1000 \
resized_base.jpeg

# add label.png to the top of resized_base.jepg
convert \
-composite \
-gravity north \
resized_base.jpeg label.png \
final_output.jpeg
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them in Imagemagick. Try the following:

```
convert base.jpeg \
-resize 780x780^ \
-gravity south \
-extent 1000x1000 \
-gravity north \
label.png \
-composite \
final_output.jpeg
```